# Low Level GUI Programming

Tags: user-interface, assembly, low-level, machine-code, microcoding

How are gui's created at the lowest level? In Java, one may type in a JFrame method and create a window. At some point, this window must be coded pixel by pixel. Is this done by assembly, machine code, or microcode in the processor?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887235/inner-workings-of-c-graphics-libraries/4887470

Comment: It depends on HW available. Any decent machine now has GPU available. These can do higher level primitives by themselves (polygons, textures, etc) and one only needs to issue appropriate request through driver. But you can still do it pixel-by-pixel, if you use some kind of software rasterizer or custom shader program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the lowest level gui's are created with electrons floating through a series of semi conductors... after that they are 0's and 1's representing binary, then machine code, then assly (depending on the CPU architecture) then programming language, are you trying to make your own gui with ought any template? Try using an image as the GUI.

[Setting background images in JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064977/setting-background-images-in-jframe)